# Eclipse, Android NDK & Sequoyah: getting rid of "make: *** No rule to make target `MyProjectName_scd.mk'. Stop."

Tags: android, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt, cocos2d-x

I build a native Android appilcation (a [Cocos2Dx](http://www.cocos2d-x.org) game) on Windows in Eclipse using [Sequoyah](http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/) to avoid command line stuff when building C++ source.

Everything builds fine except I get following error from time to time:

> C/C++ problem. make: *** No rule to make target `MyProjectName_scd.mk'.  Stop. [Discovery Options] page in project properties.

I do not have any MyProjectName_scd.mk in my project, only a MyProjectName.mk one.

Nevertheless all shared libraries are, actually, built and if I delete this error message manualy (from contextual menu) the app works fine both on device and on emulator.

I have to remove this error message manualy each time it appears, because if I don't I get a message box containing: "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running application" and can't launch the app. That's really annoying.

Any ideas how to fix it?

[Windows 7 x86, Eclipse 4.2.0 | CDT 8.1.0.201206111645, Android NDK r8]

Comment: I have the same issue.  Note that building a second time is another way to remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332522

Essentially, you need to go to:

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> CDT GCC Buildin Compiler Settings [Shared]

Then add to "Command to get compiler specs":

-std=c++11

That should do it!

Comment: Actually, this appears not to work with gcc 4.6 (the version that I have).

Comment: This solution doesn't fix the problem, I get this problem in spite of making above changes

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to you project Properties->c/C++ Build->Discovery options and uncheck "Report path detection problems" or just uncheck Automate discovery of paths and symbols